# perl Net::FTP LS with subdirectories

Tags: perl, ftp

The LS command is not giving what I expect in Net::FTP.  I expected it to return an array of strings (filenames), but I get an array, containing an array of strings.

```
use strict;
use Net::FTP::Common;

my ($host, $user, $pw) = ('<ftp site>', 'user', 'pw');
my $ftp = new Net::FTP($host) || die;
$ftp->login($user, $pw) || die;

my $pwd = $ftp->pwd();
my $subDir = 'subdir/';
my $pattern = '*.txt';
$ftp->cwd($subDir); 

$ftp->pasv(); # passive mode
my @files = $ftp->ls($pattern) || die;

$ftp->cwd($pwd);
```

The files array looks like this, for example:

@files[@array[0]] = 'filename.txt';

I've also tried not Changing Directories, and just doing `$ftp->ls('subdir/*.txt');` with the same results.

Why is it doing this? I am misunderstanding the return value?  This is on WINDOWS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you should be using

```
use Net::FTP;
```

instead of

```
use Net::FTP::Common;
```

since you use Net::FTP and not Net::FTP::Common.

Now on to your problem.

---

The documentation says:

> In an array context, returns a list of lines returned from the server. In a scalar context, returns a reference to a list.

which surely means

> In list context, returns a list of the lines returned by the server. In scalar context, returns a reference to an array of these lines.

You're calling it in scalar context. You want

```
my $files = $ftp->ls($pattern)
   or die;  # || would work, just not idiomatic.

for my $file (@$files) {
   ...
}
```

You could call `ls` in list context, then then you'd sacrifice error checking.

```
# No way to determine whether empty means error or no files.
my @files = $ftp->ls($pattern);

for my $file (@files) {
   ...
}
```

Comment: I don't understand how you are saying "my @files = $ftp->ls($pattern) || die;" is a scalar context, as I am assigning to an array?  And that I need to assign to a scalar variable to use a list context?  Your solution does work. I would expect to have a 1D array, when assigned to an array, and a reference to said array, when assigned to a scalar.  Not an array, containing an array of filenames when assigned to an array.

Comment: I said `ls` is evaluated in scalar context (by which I mean `$ftp->ls($pattern)`). No, it's not assigned to an array. It's the LHS operand of `||`. The LHS of `||` has evaluate to a boolean, so it has to evaluate to a scalar.

Comment: If you did assign the result to the array, you would get a "1D array". I showed you that in my second snippet.